# Is it possible to make network request when app in background?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, background-process

Dev Environment :

- Xcode 8, XCode 9
- AFNetworking for network request

My app need to upload some media to server, when its done i need to call the api to POST some JSON Data to server **in both case Application  in Foreground and Background**

***My problem is:***

**When application is active**, i making request upload media to server **(request 1)** and press Home button **(application enter background)**. All the media was uploading success in the background, **in success block of upload media request (request 1)** i making another request to POST some JSON data to server **(request 2)** but this request **(request 2)** can't excute in the background. When i enter the application **(application enter foreground)**. **(request 2)** trigger automatically.

I need to make **(request 2)** execute in the background. Is it possible to do this?

Please help ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

At background upload file that you need apply more time.

The iOS has 3mius give you using.

You can review "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler".

Comment: I have no problem with the upload request. All file was upload success in the background. But the request in success block of uploading request not excute in the background. Its the problem